# Gesture Recognizer Unresponsive After Time

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer that seems to become unresponsive after some time. It seems correlated to time passing and probably correlated with the app losing the active state and going into the background.

I often encounter the problem when I first reopen the app and try a long press or swipe, neither work. If I go to a different view controller and then return, that reload causes the gesture recognizers to start working again!

```
  let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPressGestureRecognized(_:)))
  mainView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
```

Any ideas around dealing with gesture recognizers becoming unresponsive like this?

Comment: did you do anything like disable userInteraction or remove gesture in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear?

Comment: In which method you execute   `mainView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)` ?

Comment: Can you add more code — at least the method where you're setting it up.

Comment: Which method in your `ViewController` contains the code stated in your question?

Comment: @SaiLi I don't have any viewWillDisappear or didDisappear implemented, so no, nothing disabled at any point.

Comment: @Hooda I add the gestures during the viewDidLoad. To be clear, they appear to add correctly the first time I open the app, but after it goes into the background and gets re-activated, the gestures don't work.

Comment: @MichaelRose It's setup in the viewDidLoad

Comment: @Malik Just added details in other comments.

Comment: Is there any code defined in `applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationDidBecomeActive`?

Comment: @Hooda nope, literally none

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach.

1. Make `longpress` a global variable
2. Add gesture in `viewWillAppear` if it doesn't exist
3. Add a notification in `viewWillAppear` for `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`
4. Remove the gesture and notification in `viewWillDisappear`

Something like this

```
var longpress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad
    longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPressGestureRecognized(_:)))
}

override viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    checkGestureAvailability()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkGestureAvailability), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
}

override viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if mainView.gestureRecognizers.contains(longpress) {
        mainView.removeGestureRecognizer(longpress)
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

func checkGestureAvailability() {
    if !mainView.gestureRecognizers.contains(longpress) {
        mainView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
    }
}
```